# How can i make a tab be accessible for chatter free license

Tags: chatter, tab

I dont know if this is possible so, I have a VFP tab. How can i make that tab be read/write by a user with just a chatter free license. Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Chatter Free users have no access to either VF or any objects so dont think its possible ."Chatter only" can be tried but test once before becoming truly sure .Also talk to your salesforce AE to explore licensing options